# What does "gifts and curses" mean?

Tags: meaning

> [...]would run about laughing and tittering carrying on her head both the **gifts and curses** given by youth. But she was swished off like a fly by young Naremma.

—[Yagnam and Other Stories](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=eZfcbtn6byIC&pg=PA238&dq=%22gifts%20and%20curses%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=sl3KUuLmMY2ZiAem0oHYDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22gifts%20and%20curses%22&f=false)

Does it simply mean the bad and the good?

Comment: Being young can be considered a gift (for example, full of energy) and a curse (for example, lacking of experience).

Comment: I think I usually see this as "both a blessing and a curse", but the meaning doesn't change by using "gift" instead of "blessing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that means pluses and minuses of something. By the way, you have found a very new idiom - it is not mentioned as such in the net dictionaries, but it definitely IS an idiom, for that phrase is repeated often enough on the net.